# UNLOAD with data containing quotes and delimiters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

### inputTable

```sql
Id | Text
----------------------
1  | Alok
2  | Alok,"Kumar",Singh
```

### targetTable

```sql
Id | Text
----------------------
0  | Vicky
```

### Problem / Question

Need to copy rows to targetTable from inpuTable using UNLOAD and COPY in Redshift. How to do it?

Redshift provides `ADDQUOTES` and `DELIMETER` which is helpful if the data did not required escaping the DELIMETER. I could not find escaping the `DELIMETER` flag in Redshift. Please suggest how to do it without writing a process to add the quotes.

### Attempt 1

```sql
UNLOAD ('select * from inputTable') TO 's3://bucket/key/unload_' manifest allowoverwrite FORMAT AS CSV DELIMITER ',' ESCAPE;
```

```
1,Alok
2,Alok,"Kumar",Singh,
```

```sql
COPY targetTable FROM 's3://bucket/key/unload_manifest' manifest FORMAT AS CSV QUOTE AS '\"' DELIMITER ','
```

COPY command fails to load the data. How to solve it using UNLOAD and COPY?

`ERROR:  ESCAPE is not supported for UNLOAD to CSV`

Comment: Why are you wanting to copy between tables with UNLOAD and COPY? Why not just insert the values directly via an SQL `INSERT` command? `INSERT INTO targetTable SELECT * from inputTable`

Comment: Because the data is very huge in inputTable that needs to be copied to targetTable and from what I understand UNLOAD and COPY is the fastest and efficient method here? @JohnRotenstein

Comment: No, doing a bulk INSERT would be faster than unloading and loading.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thanks really for letting me know this. Where can i read about the differences in the two approach in the documentation and benchmarks?

Comment: Frankly, I don't recall reading any advice to UNLOAD and COPY. There is something similar when it comes to a [Deep Copy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/performing-a-deep-copy.html), where sometimes it is better to create a new table rather than insert into an existing table, but that in your situation it depends on the size of each of your tables. Unless you are talking about millions or billions or rows, simply inserting the data should be fine. But... I highly encourage you to test the performance of both methods and base your choice on the results you discover.

Comment: Sure, I would get back with the benchmarks in some days. Going to launch both the methods with a flag and measure it. Thanks @JohnRotenstein

Answer (score 1):

`ESCAPE`, `ADDQUOTES` and `REMOVEQUOTES` solves the problem.

```sql
UNLOAD ('select * from inputTable') TO 's3://bucket/key/unload_' manifest allowoverwrite ADDQUOTES ESCAPE DELIMITER ',';
```

```sql
COPY targetTable FROM 's3://bucket/key/unload_manifest' manifest REMOVEQUOTES ESCAPE DELIMITER ',';
```

This solves it.